# object as parameter between classes java

Tags: java

I'm doing a hotel reservation. I have this class, where I create most of the arguments :

```
public class Habitaciones {

    boolean ocupado;
    int tipo;
    int ID;
    GregorianCalendar fecha;
    GregorianCalendar fechafinal;


    public Habitaciones(boolean _ocupado, int _tipo, int _ID) {
        ocupado = _ocupado;
        tipo = _tipo;
        ID= _ID;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public boolean getOcupado() {
        return ocupado;
    }

    public void setOcupado(boolean ocupado) {
        this.ocupado = ocupado;
    }

    public int getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(int tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public Calendar getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(GregorianCalendar fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public Calendar getFechafinal() {
        return fechafinal;
    }

    public void setFechafinal(GregorianCalendar fechafinal) {
        this.fechafinal = fechafinal;
    }           
}
```

In another class, I have the default info:

```
public class Hotel {

    static Habitaciones[] cuartos = new Habitaciones[6];

    public Hotel() {
        cuartos[0] = (new Habitaciones(false, 1,1));
        cuartos[1] = (new Habitaciones(false, 1,2));
        cuartos[2] = (new Habitaciones(false, 2,3));
        cuartos[3] = (new Habitaciones(false, 2,4));
        cuartos[4] = (new Habitaciones(false, 3,5));
        cuartos[5] = (new Habitaciones(false, 3,6));
    }
```

Now I want to return that "cuartos" object so I can make another class to fill it like, I'm trying to call it from the menu, but it says this variable does not exist.

**case 2:**

```
SegundoReservar miReserva = new SegundoReservar();
miReserva.SegReservarHab(cuartos);`
```

My problem is that I can do it in the same class, but don't know how to call an object from another class, or how to create it.

This is a homework for my first program course.  The point is to use vectors but is killing me. I'm super junior, so, any explanation would be apreciated.

Comment: post the stacktrace error

Comment: Take a look at this. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm

Comment: If you want to have access to the `cuartos` in your `Hotel` from another class, you should add a `public Habitaciones[] getCuartos() { return cuartos; }`

Answer (score 0):

Create a public `getCuartos` method just as you did the getters in `Habitaciones`, which returns the object you need. Then your method call becomes:

```
miReserva.SegReservarHab(hotel.getCuartos());
```

Answer (score 0):

`Cuartos` is static defined in the class Hotel: you can access to it by doing:

```
SegundoReservar miReserva = new SegundoReservar();
miReserva.SegReservarHab(Hotel.cuartos);`
```

but please be aware that the `Cuartos` array will have some `Habitaciones` **ONLY after** you create somewhen an object of the class Hotel...

some nullPointerexcetions can happen in the code if you dont consider that...

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Hotel {
        private Habitaciones[] cuartos; 

    public Hotel() {
        cuartos[0] = (new Habitaciones(false, 1,1));
        cuartos[1] = (new Habitaciones(false, 1,2));
        cuartos[2] = (new Habitaciones(false, 2,3));
        cuartos[3] = (new Habitaciones(false, 2,4));
        cuartos[4] = (new Habitaciones(false, 3,5));
        cuartos[5] = (new Habitaciones(false, 3,6));
    }

    public Habitaciones[] getHabitaciones()
    {
       return cuartos;
    }
```

Then in the Menu you should do this:

1- Create a hotel instance

```
Hotel hotel = new Hotel();
```

This initialize the cuartos field by calling the constructor.

2- You can now get the data calling the function getHabitaciones

```
hotel.getHabitaciones();
```

i think that you must set the "cuartos" field to private